# Angular 4 wizard-Pass data between wizard tab

Tags: angular

I am developing application in which I have mentioned different functionality in wizard tabs.For each tab I have developed component which is loaded when user will click on tab.

1. Personal Information tab (default tab) for Employee registration
2. Employee Contract Creation Tab

On First tab, User is filling information and save information by calling rest api.

How I can pass created record Id to second tab as without employee I can not create contract and leaves.

```
<div class="main-content" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="wizard-container">
                <div class="card wizard-card" data-color="rose" id="wizardProfile">
                    <form action="" method="">
                        <div class="wizard-header" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">

                        </div>
                        <div class="wizard-navigation custom-wizard-navigation">
                            <ul id="ulSellerCustomer" class="nav nav-pills">
                                <li id="basic" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a  (click)="setActive('PersonalInformation')" [routerLink]="['PersonalInformation']">Personal Information</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="location" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a  (click)="setActive('contract')" [routerLink]="['contract']">Contract</a>
                                </li>
                                 <li id="applyleaves" class="col-sm-4">
                                <a  (click)="setActive('applyleaves')" [routerLink]="['applyleaves']">Apply Leaves</a>
                            </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can use a service to share the employee data between the components.

Comment: zgue: any example or article which u can suggest

Comment: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-share-data-between-components.html first google result